# How would I write this url pattern in python 3.6/django1.11? (it is currently in python 2.7/django1.7)

Tags: django, python-2.7, python-3.x, url-pattern

I am very new, and I am doing a tutorial, that is a little bit old. I keep getting an error that this cannot import name 'patterns' then something about include, then syntax and so on.  So what is wrong this section? How would I write it current day? Thank you for your time.

```
    from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
    from django.contrib import admin
    from djangonote.views import home_view


    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$', home_view, name='home'),
        url(r'^notes/', include('notes.urls', namespace='notes')),
    )
```

The reply below fixed that issue, thank you Exprator! 
I now get the issue: 
NameError: name 'notes' is not defined.
What does that mean?
Ty for your time.

Comment: patterns function is deprecated in django

Comment: `patterns()` was deprecated in 1.8, and removed in 1.10.

Comment: If the tutorial uses `patterns` then it's very out of date. The fix is easy, but you might be better to look for a new tutorial to avoid other issues like this.

Answer (score 1):

```
    from django.conf.urls import  include, url
    from django.contrib import admin
    from djangonote.views import home_view


    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', home_view, name='home'),
        url(r'^notes/', include('notes.urls', namespace='notes')),
]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That definitely fixed that problem. When I try to run the server, I get the error: NameError: name 'notes' is not defined....what does that mean?

Comment: can you post the full stacktrace so that it will be easy for us to understand where exactly the error is